# Zend Framework Routing Technique

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I would like to know if this method of setting up routing in Zend Framework would be considered a reasonable approach - I am quite new to using ZF.

In my bootstrap file I have a method set up like this:

```
protected function _initRouting()
{
    $zfc  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $zfc->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute(
        'home',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '', 
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
        )
    );

    $router->addRoute(
        'saveStory',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'save-story/:date/:seolink/:saveStory', 
            array(
                'controller' => 'story',
                'action' => 'index',
                'saveStory' => 1
            )
        )
    );
```

etc etc with all my routes.

This works fine and I like the clarity of specifying routes like this but have a nagging feeling that more experienced ZF programmers would tell me that it is not the best way and that I should not do it in the bootstrap and that I should specify the routes in a seperate config file. If this is the case what form would the config file take and how and where would I read it.

Any advice would be appreciated....Because my technique works this question is more a stylistic question - what is the most 'elegant' approach.....Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just down to personal preference. Like you, I prefer to define my routes in code, but some people prefer config files (and if you want to try this there are several examples in the manual).

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, thats reassuring!